# Batch optimization of PNGs for iphone/ipad display as xcode does

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, png

I'm working on a magazine viewer for ipad and I'm struggling with the performance.

I figured out that the most expensive part of displaying the pngs is the loading process.
I know that xcode is able to optimize pngs during the build and such images are loaded much faster.  But I can't include all images in to the build as it will be huge.

Do you know how to optimize an arbitrary png without including it in the build process?

Do you know what is the best format for iphone? I think that pngs should use RGB-8888 color scheme but I'm not sure what else is important.

Maybe you know exact params for imagemagick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found  a good article about png optimization for iphone:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html

It seams that xcode uses this command:
`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/iphoneos-optimize`

It appears that the above command uses a modified version of pngcrush to optimize pngs and transform the color channels:
`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -iphone -f 0 orig.png optimized.png`

And the optimization is really helpful. I've got 5 time faster image loading!

Comment: After running that command on my image I saved about 0.55% but it went all transparent :/

Comment: @Craig: Once optimized, you cannot reliably open that PNG any longer with any image viewer or image processing app; the resulting PNG is not standard conform and is only guaranteed to be used within an iOS application. So did the image go all transparent even when being loaded on iOS? Further are you user the image is not fully transparent, since iphoneos-optimize does alpha channel premultiplication, so the alpha channel will be considered during rendering even in situation that would otherwise ignore alpha values completely.

Answer (score 5):

The best results I know of are achieved with [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.pornel.net/), which I use myself for PNGs that are not deployed via Xcode. It uses `pngcrush` and some other PNG optimization tools to achieve best compression. As far as I know, it doesn't employ alpha premultiplication and byte swapping though. ImageOptim also has a nice GUI with drag-and-drop support and can crush multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: ImageOptim is great but Xcode for iOS undoes the optimisation. See http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/.

Comment: @porneL I'd seen that before but I didn't read it as you definitely recommending that we turn off the iOS compression in Xcode.  Is that what you'd recommend to do in general?

Comment: @Danyal Aytekin: [In my benchmark](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html) file size had bigger impact on speed than Xcode's optimisation, so if you can get smaller files with ImageOptim, they'll be faster to load too.

Answer (score 2):

We used [Pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) to compress huge number of PNGs. You can try this too. And also if you don't need transparency then instead of PNG you can try JPG too. But you may go through a number of trial-and-error process for this, comparing the size and quality trade-off many times.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with imagemagick. So can't tell anything regarding that.

Comment: I only care about the loading speed. Size doesn't matter. But I will try pngcrush it seams that it is also used by xcode

Comment: Loading time depends on the size of the things that you are loading. Don't it?

Comment: Sort of. According to time profiler the app spends most of its time transforming the image. Reading the file isn't that expensive.

Comment: but anyway Pngcrush is the way to go as it is used by iphoneos-optimize command I've put below.

Answer (score 2):

In [my benchmark](http://imageoptim.com/tweetbot.html) file size turned out to be more important than Xcode preprocessing (Xcode files were larger and *slower* to load).

Best way to reduce PNG file size is to convert it to PNG8+alpha format — you can do that [in batch with pngquant](http://pngquant.org) (or tweak manually with [GUI](http://pngmini.com)).

However, if in your case conversion from RGBA to premultiplied BGRA is what is taking the most time, then [a fork of AdvanceCOMP with XCode proprietary extensions added](https://github.com/scribd/advancecomp) will let you batch convert PNGs to iOS's native format.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experimenting with pngnq, pngquant, pngcrush, optipng, etc.

For my set of PNGs, I've achieved minimum file size with pngquant, pngnq and pngcrush

```
Dir.glob("**/*.png").each do |file|
  ['pngnq -e .png -f', 'pngquant -f -speed 1 -ext .png', 'pngcrush'].each do |command|
    puts "#{command} #{file}"
    `#{command} #{file}`
  end
end
```

More details at: http://l4u.github.com/blog/2012/04/02/optimizing-file-sizes-of-png-images/

Comment: Please include some code in your answers.  We prefer answers that are not just links and have their own content.

Comment: I know.  But it would be nice if people didn't have to follow a link away from the site to get their answer.

Comment: Running pngquant after pngnq won't do anything, as the image will have 256 colors already. You'd be better off only running `pngquant`.

Answer (score 1):

I've lots and lots of space using [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/), but I haven't done any testing to see if decoding the image slows it down at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://texturepacker.com

It can not only optimize PNGs but also reduce colors e.g. to RGBA4444 or RGB565 which decreases ping size dramatically and improves rendering on the devices.

You could also export PVR files for devices that support it (e.g. iOS, some Android)

And it also supports scaling down images for low res devices.

Comment: Dumb quantization to fixed levels like 4444 unnecessarily loses quality. I wrote [median cut posterizer](https://github.com/pornel/mediancut-posterizer) ([GUI](http://pngmini.com)) that chooses levels perceptually — it doesn't make big difference to deflate algorithm, but makes to humans.