# Appending a png pHYs chunk in php

Tags: php, binary, png, chunks

I'm trying to tack on some information about the physical size for printing my PNGs just before they are generated.

Reading the [libpng doc](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html) and the pHYs chunk specifications has been helpful but I just can't seem to crack it.

I have tried adding this chunk in the most manual and simplest way possible, however, the .png file ends up corrupted. Am I missing an encoding trick?

For the CRC computation I have used the 32-bit result of [this site](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html), having plugged in the ASCII values for the chunk that the code below gives me.

```
$encoded = $_POST['imgdata'];
$encoded = str_replace(' ', '+', $encoded);
$decoded=  base64_decode($encoded);

$test = explode('IDAT',$decoded);
$ppu='00000000000000000010111000100011';  //32-bit integer for the pixels per unit
$dppu=bindec($ppu);
$test[0].=sprintf("%c",bindec('00000000000000000000000000001001')) //length, also 32-bit
    .'pHYs'                                                      //type
    .  sprintf("%c",$dppu)                             //Pixels per unit, x axis
    . sprintf("%c",$dppu)                             //Pixels per unit, y axis
    .'1'                                                 //Units in metres (1 byte)
    .  sprintf("%c",  bindec(base_convert('0x0BFAAA7E', 16, 2))) //CRC (32-bit)
    .'IDAT';
$fintest=implode($test);

echo $fintest;
```

Please let me know whether hacking it in like this is likely to work. I am also unsure about my 32-bit integers: is zero-padding them as I am doing the correct way to make them 32-bit?

Comment: Isn't "%c" going to just print an 8-bit character?  $ppu, $dppu, and the CRC are 4-byte (32-bit) integers.  You could split each of those into 4 bytes and then sprintf() each byte.

Comment: Do these functions `explode` and `implode` what I suspect they do: uncompressing and then recompressing *only* the `IDAT` chunk? That's an error: `pHYs` is a separate chunk, independent of the compressed `IDAT`.

Comment: The `pHYs` chunk should be placed before the `IDAT`, I am exploding it at the chunk name to append it at this point. I will look more into the `"%c"` formatting standard, I was not aware the bit count wouldn't "translate" from an integer into the corresponding ASCII. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having spent the day on this, I found that the way to do this was to translate everything byte by byte. Following the docs, the `pHYs` chunk takes:

- 4 bytes for chunk (only the data) length
- 4 bytes for chunk type (the characters 'pHYs')
- 9 bytes for chunk data: 4 bytes each for x- and y-density and 1 byte for unit choice
- 4 bytes for the CRC

I wrote all this as a binary string, padding the bytes with 0 as necessary.
It then turns out that the `chr()` function correctly encodes this to be used in the PNG file, unlike the `sprintf("%c",$string)` method I use in the question. Here is the code

```
$encoded = $_POST['imgdata'];
$encoded = str_replace(' ', '+', $encoded);
$decoded=  base64_decode($encoded);

$binstring='00000000000000000000000000001001' //4-byte length
        . '01110000010010000101100101110011' //4-byte type or 'pHYs'
        . '000000000000000000101110001000110000000000000000001011100010001100000001' //9-byte data
        . base_convert('0x0BFAAA7E', 16, 2); //4-byte CRC
foreach (str_split($binstring,8) as $b) {
    $on.=chr(bindec($b));
}
```

The $on variable is then appended to the position just before the 4 bytes of the `IDAT` chunk length.

Comment: I want to update the dpi of png to 300. Can you please mention the code. (trytusar@gmail.com)

Comment: Pasting the code as is in the snippet above should be enough to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Alex's answer and correcting minor errors in his code, I'll try to provide a working example on **how to append a PNG pHYs chunk, or set PNG image resolution in pure PHP** without resampling image. The following code reads data from *file.png* and sends modified image to the standard output.

```
<?php

  // Read file data
  $data = file_get_contents('file.png');

  // Pixels per inch
  $ppi = 300;

  // Unit conversion PPI to PPM
  $ppm = round($ppi * 100 / 2.54);

  $ppm_bin = str_pad(base_convert($ppm, 10, 2), 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

  // Split PNG data at first IDAT chunk
  $data_splitted = explode('IDAT', $data, 2);

  // Generate "pHYs" chunk data

  // 4-byte data length
  $length_bin = '00000000000000000000000000001001';
  // 4-byte type or 'pHYs'
  $chunk_name_bin = '01110000010010000101100101110011';
  // 9-byte data
  $ppu_data_bin = 
           $ppm_bin // Pixels per unit, x axis
          .$ppm_bin // Pixels per unit, y axis
          .'00000001'; // units - 1 for meters
  // Calculate 4-byte CRC
  $hash_buffer = '';
  foreach(str_split($chunk_name_bin.$ppu_data_bin, 8) as $b)
    $hash_buffer .= chr(bindec($b));
  $crc_bin = str_pad(base_convert(crc32($hash_buffer), 10, 2), 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  // Create chunk binary string
  $binstring = $length_bin
          . $chunk_name_bin
          . $ppu_data_bin
          . $crc_bin;

  // Convert binary string to raw
  $phys_chunk_raw = '';
  foreach(str_split($binstring, 8) as $b)
    $phys_chunk_raw .= chr(bindec($b));

  // Insert "pHYs" chunk before first IDAT tag
  $new_image_data = substr($data_splitted[0], 0, strlen($data_splitted[0]) - 4)
        . $phys_chunk_raw
        . substr($data_splitted[0], strlen($data_splitted[0]) - 4, 4)
        . 'IDAT'
        . $data_splitted[1];

  // Output modified image
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  echo $new_image_data;

?>
```

Or, more elegant snippet that does the same thing (found at [habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/post/56588/)):

```
<?php

  // Read file data
  $data = file_get_contents('file.png');

  // Pixels per inch
  $ppi = 300;

  $incPos = strpos($data, 'IDAT') - 4; // Get chunk position
  $chunk = 'pHYs'.pack('NNc', round($ppi/0.0254), round($ppi/0.0254), 1); // Pack chunk type + chunk data
  $incData = pack('N', 9).$chunk.pack('N', crc32($chunk)); // Append chunk's size at beginning, it's crc at the end
  $new_image_data = substr_replace($data, $incData, $incPos, 0);

  // Output modified image
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  echo $new_image_data;

?>
```

The only thing that you must remember: this approach *works only with PNG files that have no pHYs chunk*. For example, generated by PHP GD, or JavaScript HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL(). If your PNG already has a pHYs chunk, you must *find and modify existing  chunk*.